# Call variable outside method

Tags: java

Hello I'm pretty new to java so I do not know everything.

My problem  is I want to check if the player has performed "setloc" command and if the player has perform it I want to set the location and then want to call it from another if statment.

```
if(p.performCommand("setloc")){
    Location location = p.getLocation();
}
if(p.getItemInHand().equals(itemstack)){
    dostuff(location);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! @RathanNaik has given a solution to your problem - however in order to learn more, I'd recommend you research the topic of "variable scope in java". Hope that helps - happy learning!

Comment: Thank you Mike have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

```
Location location;
if(p.performCommand("setloc")){
         location = p.getLocation();
}
if(p.getItemInHand().equals(itemstack)){

         if(location==null)
             location = p.getLocation();

        dostuff(location);
}
```